# pythonic way for nested loops checking items against two or more list

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

I want to check items against two lists in python which are again put in the one big list
In my codes , combinedList is big list and row1 and row2 are sub-list.

I need to check items in row1 and row2 against each other. I got rough idea in psudo code however , since i m new to python . is there any good codes for checking against two list for their item without repeating the same pair more than once?

```
row1 = [a,b,c,d,....]
row2 = [s,c,e,d,a,..]

combinedList = [row1 ,row2]

for ls in combinedList:
        **for i=0 ; i < length of ls; i++
            for j= i+1 ; j <length of ls; j++
                do something here item at index i an item at index j**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> row1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> row2 = ['s', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'a']
>>> seen = set()             #keep a track of already visited pairs in this set
>>> for x,y in product(row1, row2):
        if (x,y) not in seen and (y,x) not in seen:
            print x,y
            seen.add((x,y))
            seen.add((y,x))
...         
a s
a c
a e
a d
a a
b s
b c
b e
b d
b a
c s
c c
c e
c d
d s
```

**Update:**

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> for x,y in combinations(row1, 2):
...     print x,y
...     
a b
a c
a d
b c
b d
c d
```

Comment: one more question, how about if i want to compare for row1 items such as "a and b, a and c , a and d , b and c , b and d, c and d" and not the reverse pairs... thanks!

Comment: @Peter use `itertools.combinations` for that. I've added a small example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`zip()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair values of two lists:

```
for row1value, row2value in zip(row1, row2):
    # do something with row1value and row2value
```

If you wanted to combine each element from row1 with each element of row2 instead (the product of the two lists), use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead:

```
from itertools import product

for row1value, row2value in product(row1, row2):
    # do something with row1value and row2value
```

`zip()` simply pairs up the lists producing `len(shortest_list)` items, `product()` pairs up each element in one list with each element in the other, producing `len(list1)` times `len(list2)` items:

```
>>> row1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> row2 = [9, 8, 7]
>>> for a, b in zip(row1, row2):
...     print a, b
... 
1 9
2 8
3 7
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for a, b in product(row1, row2):
...     print a, b
... 
1 9
1 8
1 7
2 9
2 8
2 7
3 9
3 8
3 7
```